# How to resolve manual date entry for jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery UI datepicker on my page and it should be possible to enter dates manually. To make it easier for the user, it should also be possible to enter a short form of the date (day and month only) and it will be resolved with the next possible date as soon as the focus is off the field.

**Sample** (german date format):

29092019 should be resolved to 29.09.2019

2909 should be resolved to 29.09.2019

0103 should be resolved to 01.03.2020 when March 1st is already over for this year.

How do I start with a problem like this?

```js
$( function() {
    $("#myDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat : "dd.mm.yy"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="myDate" />
```

Comment: "29042019 should be resolved to 24.09.2019" is that right? Shouldn't it be `24092019 -> 24.09.2019`?

Comment: you're right, that's a typo. Change that now!

Comment: Ok, thanks to the given answers we're pretty close. I just need to find out how I can validate the parsed dates! Currently it is possible to get values like e.g. "40.15.2050" or "30.02.2019", which shouldn't be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Look what happens when you run this in the console: `new Date("30.02.2019")` - it returns `Invalid Date` - use this for validation. You should read on JavaScript's Date object.

Comment: **** THIS QUESTION IS CLOSED - NO MORE ANSWERS REQUIRED! ****

The bounty will go to @scott6 for his amazing help over the last few weeks. I just have to wait 24hours until I can award him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

to integrate with jQuery's date picker, you can do it like below

**Edits:**

- add invalid date validation, & return empty string on invalid dates
- fix date validation: add leap day validation
- fix monDt variable (add getMonth+1 as month in JS starts with 0)

```js
$(function(){
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy'
});
$('.datepicker').on('blur',function(){parseInputDate(this);});

})

function parseInputDate(elm) {
  var currDate = new Date(),
      monDt = (('0'+(currDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+('0'+currDate.getDate()).slice(-2)), // get current month+date to compare
      inputVal = $(elm).val().match(/\d{2}/gi); // split date components into array of [dd,mm,yy,yy]
  // another date validation, by comparing parameters and date object result 
    var isValidDate = function(yyyy,mm,dd) {
 var dt = new Date(yyyy,parseInt(mm,10)-1,dd);
    return (dt.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0'+dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) == yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
  }  
  if (inputVal!=null && inputVal.length>=2) {    
    var year = currDate.getFullYear();
    if (monDt>(inputVal[1]+inputVal[0])) year++;
    // generate formatted text based on date component count
    // add date validation to catch invalid dates using (new Date('yyyy-mm-dd')).getTime() which will return NaN on invalid date
    var result = (inputVal.length==2 && isValidDate(year,inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0]+'.'+inputVal[1]+'.'+year) || 
      (inputVal.length==3 && isValidDate('20'+inputVal[2],inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0]+'.'+inputVal[1]+'.20'+inputVal[2]) || 
      (inputVal.length==4 && isValidDate(inputVal[2]+inputVal[3],inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && inputVal[0]+'.'+inputVal[1]+'.'+inputVal[2]+inputVal[3]) ||
      ''; // set empty on invalid dates
    $(elm).val(result);
  } else $(elm).val('');   
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myDate" class="datepicker" />
```

And this is an example for multiple datepicker with some constraints. You can adjust to what you need :)

& return date string based on datepicker's format

```js
$(function(){
 initDatePicker();
})

function initDatePicker(){
 // do a loop for custom property on each element
 $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        // you can find available formats here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate
  $(this).datepicker({
   dateFormat:'yy.mm.dd'
     });
  // set minimum date from data attribute. 
  if (typeof $(this).data('mindate') != 'undefined') {
   $(this).datepicker('option','minDate',$(this).data('mindate'));
  }
  // set maximum date from data attribute. 
  if (typeof $(this).data('maxdate') != 'undefined') {
   $(this).datepicker('option','maxDate',$(this).data('maxdate'));
  }
  
  $(this).on('change',function(){
   parseInputDate(this);
   // now, set date relations :) 
   if (typeof $(this).data('nextelem') != 'undefined') {
    $($(this).data('nextelem')).datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
   }
   if (typeof $(this).data('prevelem') != 'undefined') {
    $($(this).data('prevelem')).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
   }
  });
  
 });
}

// get date function taken from : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range
function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
 date = $.datepicker.parseDate( $(element).datepicker('option','dateFormat'), element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
 date = null;
  }
  return date;
}

function parseInputDate(elm) {
  var currDate = new Date(),
      monDt = (('0'+(currDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+('0'+currDate.getDate()).slice(-2)), // get current month+date to compare
      inputVal = $(elm).val().match(/\d{2}/gi), // split date components into array of [dd,mm,yy,yy]
      format = $(elm).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"); // get current element's datepicker format
      
  // check if it's already a valid entry, then do nothing 
  if ($(elm).val() == $.datepicker.formatDate(format,$(elm).datepicker('getDate'))) return;    
  
  var isValidDate = function(yyyy,mm,dd) {
 var dt = new Date(yyyy,parseInt(mm,10)-1,dd);
 return (dt.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0'+dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) == yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
  } 
  var getDateString = function(yyyy,mm,dd) {
     var dt = new Date(yyyy,parseInt(mm,10)-1,dd);
     // get datepicker format & get date string using datepicker's formatDate function
     return $.datepicker.formatDate($(elm).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"),dt);
  }
 
  if (inputVal!=null && inputVal.length>=2) {    
      var year = currDate.getFullYear();
      if (monDt>(inputVal[1]+inputVal[0])) year++;
      // generate formatted text based on date component count
   // add date validation to catch invalid dates, & generate date string according to datepicker format 
  var result = (inputVal.length==2 && isValidDate(year,inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && getDateString(year,inputVal[1],inputVal[0])) || 
       (inputVal.length==3 && isValidDate('20'+inputVal[2],inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && getDateString('20'+inputVal[2],inputVal[1],inputVal[0])) || 
       (inputVal.length==4 && isValidDate(inputVal[2]+inputVal[3],inputVal[1],inputVal[0]) && getDateString(inputVal[2]+inputVal[3],inputVal[1],inputVal[0])) ||
       ''; // set empty on invalid dates
      $(elm).val(result);
  } else $(elm).val('');  

  // add validation to invalidate out-of-range value
  // get selected/entered date
  var cdate = $(elm).datepicker('getDate');
  // get range
  var minDateAttr = $(elm).datepicker("option", "minDate");
  var maxDateAttr = $(elm).datepicker("option", "maxDate");
  // get datepicker instance
  var inst = $('#myDate').data("datepicker");
  var isValid = false;
  if (minDateAttr!=null) {
 // get range as date object
 var minDateObj = $.datepicker._determineDate(inst, minDateAttr, new Date());
 if (minDateObj<=cdate) isValid = true
  }
  if (isValid && maxDateAttr!=null) {
 // get range as date object
 var maxDateObj = $.datepicker._determineDate(inst, maxDateAttr, new Date());
 if (maxDateObj>=cdate) isValid = true
  }
  if (!isValid) $(elm).val('');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


Dates : 
<input type="text" id="myDate" class="datepicker" data-nextelem="#myDate2"  data-mindate="-20" maxlength="10" style="width:80px" /> -
<input type="text" id="myDate2" class="datepicker" data-prevelem="#myDate" data-nextelem="#myDate3"  maxlength="10" style="width:80px"/> -
<input type="text" id="myDate3" class="datepicker" data-prevelem="#myDate2"  data-maxdate="+2y" maxlength="10" style="width:80px"/>
```

Comment: This sample works wonderful and nearly as described. There's just one little thing missing: the input field should work with standard jQuery UI datepicker as well. It should be possible to use the picker OR the direct input. When I am adding your function to my current textbox it does only work for the datepicker but NOT for the direct input. I have tested with selector ".datepicker" as well as with ".hasDatepicker". The first one ist the class jQuery datepicker uses to generate the picker at all, the second class is the generated one.

Comment: NEARLY GOOD!! I just need to find out how I can validate the parsed dates! Currently it is possible to get values like e.g. "40.15.2050" or "30.02.2019", which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi there shouldn't be any problem. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: yes, this is working. The only remaining problem is, that the user can still enter invalid dates

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi no problem.. check my updated answer :)

Comment: pretty, pretty close! But it's still possible to enter February, 30th for example.

Comment: You are brilliant!! Thank you so much for your effort. I have to watch very closely, what you have done here....!!

Comment: I think I've just found a bug. When entering 1002 it is being parsed correctly to 10.02.2020. Entering 2002 is is being parsed to 20.02.2019. Strange

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi : oops.. sorry for that, getMonth should be added by 1.. answer updated :)

Comment: but now every parsed Date is a 2020 date, not 2019 anymore. Try 2004 => 20.04.2020, but it should be 20.04.2019, as long as that day is not over for this year

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi another oops :D getMonth addition should be on bracket to avoid casting as string.. answer updated.. btw i've add another example for you to implement on multiple datepicker with some constraints

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! Now I was able to solve my problems with the different types of datepickers on my page. I needed to solve different min and maxDates on different occasions, some with and some without relations - and it's all possible with the above code and a few additional tweaks here and there. I learned so much on this task, that was much fun! So, thanks again for your time and that awesome, re-usable solution! :-XXXX

Comment: May I ask an additional but important question? I need to keep the function flexible. Date format can be dd.mm.yyyy but also dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or whatever. How can I adopt the function to the new needs?

Comment: @JonSnow : no problem.. you can do that with built in `$.datepicker.formatDate` function.. see my updated answer :)

Comment: => Superhero!! Thank you so much :-XXX

Comment: It works perfect for dd.mm.yy as well as for dd/mm/yy. But unfortunatly not for yy-mm-dd. Do I have to change something extra for the year being the first element here?

Comment: what I need to mention here is, that the date is being resolved correctly when typing 2005 - this gets resolved to 2019-05-20. But the datepicker itself does not work anymore then. You can pick any date but the result is empty. I don't understand why

Comment: @JonSnow ah..yes.. We need to check the value whether its already valid or not. Please check my updated answer

Comment: One extra line only... I would never ever have found that!! Now it's really brilliant and perfect. I have tested with different date formats (dd.mm.yy, dd/mm/yy, mm/dd/yy and also yy-mm-dd) - all dates get resolved correctly while all datepickers do work as well. How can I thank you !!??

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it - comments below:

```js
// Some sample dates
let userDates = [
    "29092019",
    "2909",
    "0103",
    "1303",
    "1403"
];

// Run the sample dates through parseUserDate()
for (let userDate of userDates) {
    console.log(userDate + ":");
    console.log(parseUserDate(userDate));
}

function parseUserDate(dateStr) {
    let parsedDate;

    // If it's 8 characters long, slice into YYYY-MM-DD
    if (dateStr.length === 8) {
        let dateSplit = [
            dateStr.slice(4),
            dateStr.slice(2, 4),
            dateStr.slice(0, 2)
        ];

        parsedDate = new Date(dateSplit.join("-"));
    }

    // 4 characters long - slice into MM-DD and prefix with YYYY later.
    else if (dateStr.length === 4) {
        let monthDay = [
            dateStr.slice(2, 4),
            dateStr.slice(0, 2)
        ].join("-");

        // The current date - this is used to check if the user date should be next year.
        let now = new Date();

        // MM-DD with the current year.
        let userDateCurrentYear = new Date(now.getFullYear() + "-" + monthDay);

        // MM-DD with next year.
        let userDateNextYear = new Date((now.getFullYear() + 1) + "-" + monthDay);

        // If the current date is past the MM-DD this year, set parsedDate to next year's date.
        if (now > userDateCurrentYear) {
            parsedDate = userDateNextYear;
        } else {
            parsedDate = userDateCurrentYear;
        }
    }

    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: How can I keep the Parser flexible for different date formats?

Comment: @JonSnow You could add an additional parameter to the function call: `parseUserDate(dateStr, dateFormat)` then split `dateStr` accordingly.